# Add quantity if the DataGridView item already exists

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have created a cart using a `DataGridView` and on the add to cart button I have this code:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim total As Integer
Dim b As Integer
a = TextBox2.Text
b = NumericUpDown56.Value
total = a * b
ShoppingCart.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Me.Label11.Text, Me.TextBox2.Text, Me.NumericUpDown56.Value, total)
Me.Hide()
ShoppingCart.Show()
```

How can I add quantity if I re-added the same item?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour]. In an attempt to clarify the question, are you saying you have added an item to the `DataGridView` and you now want to know how to update the quantity of that item? Also I would look at giving your controls better names. `Label11`, `TextBox2` and `NumericUpDown56` means absolutely nothing to us and it will only cause you more grief down the line.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to answer this without knowing quite what the textbox and updowncounter do... but assuming you only expect the updown counter to change...

You can iterate through the data and hunt for the same text in the first column

```
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    a = TextBox2.Text
    b = NumericUpDown56.Value
    total = a * b
    Dim Updated As Boolean
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In ShoppingCart.DataGridView1.Rows
        If CType(row.Cells(0).Value, String) = Me.Label11.text Then
            row.Cells(2).Value = CType(row.Cells(0).Value, Integer) + b
            row.Cells(3).Value = CType(row.Cells(3).Value, Integer) + total
            Updated = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not Updated Then ShoppingCart.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Me.Label11.Text, Me.TextBox2.Text, Me.NumericUpDown56.Value, total)
    Me.Hide()
    ShoppingCart.Show()
```

Though personally I'd bind the datagridview to a of List(of T) (t = a class that retains your properties) and search / modify that instead, then rebind the list.

Something along these lines...

```
Private Class cls_Cart_Item
    Public Property Item_Name As String
    Public Property Whatever_TExtbox2_IS_SUpposed_to_be As Integer
    Public Quantity As Integer
    Public Sub New(wName As String, wWhatever_TExtbox2_IS_SUpposed_to_be As Integer, wQuantity As Integer)
        Item_Name = wName
        Whatever_TExtbox2_IS_SUpposed_to_be = wWhatever_TExtbox2_IS_SUpposed_to_be
        Quantity = wQuantity
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property Total As Integer
        Get
            Return Whatever_TExtbox2_IS_SUpposed_to_be * Quantity
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
Private Cart As New List(Of cls_Cart_Item)

Private Sub Add_Or_Update()
    ShoppingCart.datagridview1.datasource = Nothing
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    a = TextBox2.Text
    b = NumericUpDown56.Value

    Dim Item As New cls_Cart_Item = Cart.Find(Function(x) x.Item_Name = Me.Label11.Text)
    If Item Is Nothing Then
        Cart.Add(New cls_Cart_Item(Me.Label11.Text, a, b))
    Else
        Item.Quantity += b
    End If
    Me.Hide()

    ShoppingCart.datagridview1.datasource = Cart

End Sub
```

Though it's hard to tell from your question where this code is coming from relative to the daraviewgrid.